# Как очистить от лишнего

Tags: c++

Допустим, есть такой код:

```
char q [5]
char w [4];
cin.getline(q,4) //если вводим 1234567890
cin.getline(w,3)//Здесь оно само заполняется
```

Я столкнулся с проблемой, что если ввести колл-во символов больше чем выделено, то происходит заполнение последующей переменной автоматически. Если ввести меньше чем выделено то все норм. Как это можно обработать?

Comment: Что значит "обработать"? Какое поведение вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, вы что-то выдумываете. Если вызов `std::cin.getline` завершился "досрочно", т.е. по достижению предельного размера буфера, а не по достижению конца строки, то в потоке `std::cin` будет выставлен `failbit`. Пока в потоке выставлен `failbit` никакие операции ввода выполняться не будут. Это приведет к тому, что второй вызов `std::cin.getline` ничего не прочитает вообще. Никакого "заполнения последующей переменной автоматически" не произойдет. Сбросить `failbit` можете только вы, но я у вас в коде ничего подобного не вижу.

Во-вторых, по вашему вопросу совершенно не ясно, в чем вы видите "проблему" и какое поведение вы хотите получить в результате. Но если задача состоит в том, чтобы пропустить непрочитанный первым вызовом `std::cin.getline` "хвост" строки, то после чтения начала вам нужно проверять `failbit`. Если он установлен, то сбрасывать его и делать

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

P.S. Предельный размер в `std::basic_istream<>::getline` - это предельный размер буфера, а не предельная длина строки. То есть в вашем примере у вас либо буферы слишком большие, либо значения, передаваемые в `getline` слишком маленькие.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего считать всю строку, не ограничивая количество символов:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```

А потом доставать нужное количество символов из `s`.